# IAM Role does not exist for EMR Notebooks

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I'm trying to create a Notebook on an Amazon EMR cluster.

I didn't find the default role for notebooks `EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole` to add as IAM. All the available roles that exists are:

[image: IAM Roles]

After adding the strategy and adding the role I got error:

> Error: Service role does not have permission to access the S3 LocationUri {}

[image]

Contents of my `EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:CancelSpotInstanceRequests",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribePrefixLists",
                "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSpotInstanceRequests",
                "ec2:DescribeSpotPriceHistory",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpointServices",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:ModifyImageAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
                "ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:DeleteVolume",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DetachVolume",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "s3:*",
                "s3:CreateBucket",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "sdb:BatchPutAttributes",
                "sdb:Select",
                "sqs:CreateQueue",
                "sqs:Delete*",
                "sqs:GetQueue*",
                "sqs:PurgeQueue",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
                "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
                "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:Describe*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/spot.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForEC2Spot*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": "spot.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**BlocNotes Stopped**
[image: BlockNotes Stopped]

Comment: Please check if desired role is present in IAM/roles or not? if not, then You have to create the role from AWS provided policies or if you want more granular control then you might have to create your own custom policy too.

Comment: @Shubhamoli Thank you for your response,  The role exists . I have added and got this error
**Error: Service role does not have permission to access the S3 LocationUri {}**

Comment: I have added a pic in my original post @Shubhamoli

Comment: Please attach necessary policies to access S3

Comment: @Shubhamoli Please have a look on my original post. What should i add more ? Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Please read this https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-roles.html in this S3 related requirements are clearly mentioned

Comment: Thank you @Shubhamoli , i read it but how can i change the json of the strategy to attach necessary policies?

Comment: Edit the policy from AWS->IAM console->policies

Comment: I have always a problem of policies . Now the notebook is created but stopped quickly. The error posted in the original post. Please have a look @Shubhamoli

Comment: I've no idea about how this mentioned notebook works and it's necessary permissions....I helped you to till role and policy creation and now regarding granular controls you've to dig around and fix yourself.

Comment: What are you selecting for Notebook Location (Emplacement du bloc-notes)? This error appears to be related to the S3 bucket you're selecting in that option but your screenshots don't show what you've selected there. Try selecting "Use a location that EMR creates" if you're not already doing that.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, go to S3 bucket and update Bucket Policy as following:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::632293491421:role/EMR_DefaultRole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-emr-resources-632293491421-eu-west-1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::632293491421:role/EMR_DefaultRole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-emr-resources-632293491421-eu-west-1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Following screenshot might help!

[image: Fix - Error: Service role does not have permission to access the S3 LocationUri]

Answer (score 1):

To create `EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole`, choose `Create default role`

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-service-role.html):

```
 If a notebook has not been created before, you can choose to create the default role.
```

Answer (score 0):

you already have "s3:*" in your policy, have this apply to the S3 bucket

explicitly, include the bucket ARN and folder path

- arn:aws:s3:::bucket
- arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*

when creating the notebook in the EMR console, also specify a folder in the path

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and when I manually added the "notesbooks" folder to my S3 drive it worked.

Comment: this is why EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole can access to s3 if atach s3 full access policy  :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-service-role.html